# How to get article count with a single entry view

Tags: count

I want to get the current article count with a single article view. So I've I'm currently viewing the fifth of ten articles, it will output '5'.

If I do this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="articles" sort="asc" limit="1"}

{count}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This always evaluates to 1, as it's the single entry view.

I've tried {absolute_count} but this provides the same result.

Any ideas, I'm open to using {query} tags but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including 'Dynamic="no"' ie

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="articles" sort="asc" limit="1" dynamic="no"}
```

https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic

Comment: Yes, but that just reutns everything in the channel.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to do this.

You could, however, do this by calling an embed that you pass the entry ID to, loop through all the articles - and when the entry id of the loop matches the embedded entry id, then you have your count. Keep in mind that the more entries in the channel, the more overhead you'll have looping through them all.

So...your single entry template would look something like the following...

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="articles" limit="1"}
    {embed="embeds/_get-entry-count" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then, in your embed...

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="articles" sort="asc"}
    {if entry_id == embed:entry_id}
        {count}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```